# INDEX & MATCH / VLOOKUP counting number of found matches instead of showing one of them

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I have two sheets in Google Sheets. In one I have two columns with values I need to find in two columns of the second one and return number of matches for each row in the first one.

```
=Iferror(INDEX ( Leads!$C$2:C$1000, ( MATCH ( $A2 & $B2,Leads!$A$2:$A$1000 & Leads!$B$2:$B$100, 0 ))),0)
```

I've been using this function and then assigning it `1` or `0` values with IF function, but it works only for a range without more than one match.

How to do it when there are more matches?

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned what format your data is in, but please try:

```
=COUNTA(QUERY(Leads!A:B,"SELECT A WHERE A = '"&Sheet1!A1&"' and B = '"&Sheet1!B1&"' "))
```

copied down to suit.

[COUNTA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093991)
[QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a countif formula would work from what you described.

If I have misunderstood your question, please share a screenshot or example of your data.

If you're specifically looking for rows which match data in both columns, you could add a helper column in column C for both sheets: `=Concat(A1,B1)` in cell C1 and drag down. Then in Cell D1 of Sheet 1, use this formula:

```
=Countif('Sheet2!'C$1:C$1000,C1)
```

And drag down.